# Advanced search in users, roles e claims ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, advanced-search

Since version 2.0, roles are optional and this was a pretty good idea but with a messy implemantation.
I don't know why properties like User.Roles and Roles.Claims were removed (now I have to add it manually and a lot of methods were removed too...) and by now I'm too afraid to ask, but this was terrible for who was adapted with those properties since creation of the ASP.NET Identity even before .NET Core.

After this complaint, let's procede to the question.

I have an user (IdentityUser) that may have one or more roles (IdentityRole). And role may have one or more claims.

I have a form where I can search users by their name, email, roles, and claims.
The fields name and email are a simple input. The fields roles and claims are multiple selects.

```
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
<select multiple id="select-role">
  <option>Choose one or more roles</option>
  <option>Admin</option>
  <option>Manager</option>
  <option>User</option>
</select>
<select multiple id="select-claim">
  <option>Choose one or more claims</option>
  <option>Can write users</option>
  <option>Can read users</option>
  <option>Can delete users</option>
  <option>Can write customers</option>
  <option>Can read customers</option>
  <option>Can delete customers</option>
</select>
```

Requirements:

- I can search users that have specific roles (one or more);
- I can search users that have specific roles (one or more) that have specific claims (one or more);
- I can search users that have specific claims (one or more) - *claims are inside roles, but user don't mention any roles in search*.

An example of search and its required result:

```
My data:
Users  | Roles     | Claims    
John   | {A, B, C} | {{A1,A2,A3}, {B2,B3}, {C3}}
Mary   | {B, C}    | {{B2,B3}, {C3}}
Joseph | {C}       | {{C3}}
```

Search users that have role A and B.
The result must be John and Mary.

Search users that have role A.
The result must be only John.

Search users that have role C and claim 1.
The result must but none.

Search users that have role A and B and claims 1 and 2.
The result must but only John.

Considering that I have these lists that I got from DB:

- Users;
- Roles;
- Claims;
- UsersInRole;
- ClaimsInRole.

How can I search in memory in these lists considering my requirements?

------ UPDATED ------

My ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post your User class. If you are using Entity Framework you can do what you want using [Eager Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx). Something like var users = context.Users.Include(x => x.Roles.Claims).Where(x => "your filter here").ToList();

Comment: I edited the post with my ApplicationUser class.
Yes, I'm using EF, but Microsoft has removed some properties from IdentityUser class and I can't include it without some extensions in my code...